# Image Repeating in CSS keyframe animation

Tags: css

So in my animation, I'm currently encountering a problem where my first image, rt1, is slightly and transparently flashing into view right before my last image rt3 is rotating into view and then does so again right after rt3 has come into view. Why is this and what can I do to stop this from occurring? I believed I stacked my images properly for my animation sequence.

Let me also note, this is only occurring in safari.. when I try running this in chrome it renders fine.

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------
Banner
--------------------------------------------------- */
#banner a#main {
background-image:
  url('../images/Animation-rotations/Beer/320x50/320x50_2x_rt1.png'),
  url('../images/Animation-rotations/Beer/320x50/320x50_2x_rt2.png'),
  url('../images/Animation-rotations/Beer/320x50/320x50_2x_rt3.png');
background-size: contain;
color: #E1E0DC;
}

#banner a#main .content {
-webkit-animation: bannerRotation 12s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0.7, 0) forwards;
background-image:
  url('../images/Animation-rotations/Beer/320x50/320x50_2x_rt1.png'),
  url('../images/Animation-rotations/Beer/320x50/320x50_2x_rt2.png'),
  url('../images/Animation-rotations/Beer/320x50/320x50_2x_rt3.png');
background-size: contain;
}


@-webkit-keyframes bannerRotation {
  0%  {
    background-image:
      url('../images/Animation-rotations/Beer/320x50/320x50_2x_rt1.png');
  } 33.3%, 66.6%  {
    background-image:
      url('../images/Animation-rotations/Beer/320x50/320x50_2x_rt2.png');
  }  66.6%, 100% {
    background-image:
      url('../images/Animation-rotations/Beer/320x50/320x50_2x_rt3.png');
  } 
}
```

Comment: Add `background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;`

Comment: Just tried that, still occurring unfortunately.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

use `background-repeat: no-repeat;`